# How to use a dropdown menu to display a list using jetpack-compose?

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to pull a list from my ui state into a dropdown menu. The state is in a data class in its own file. A function to return the list is located in a view model file. The user is supposed to be able to input a name in the provided textfield, the name is then saved in the state, then when the user clicks the menu icon button the list of names should 'drop down' in the dropdown menu. However, the names are not appearing in the dropdown menu. Logcat does show that the size of the list(from the view model) of the state is updated, however, the variable that I am using to call the list is showing as zero.
I have spent quite some time researching and trying to apply fixes but I am not sure what I am doing wrong. My code and some snippets from my debugging are attached. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
This is my first time posting, I am sorry if this is too much code or not enough information.

State Ui:

```
data class UserNameUiState(
    val userName: String
)
```

View Model:

```
class DropDownMenuViewModel: ViewModel() {

    // Captures state for user names
    private var _userName = mutableStateListOf<UserNameUiState>()

   // Returns list of user names
    fun getUserNameList(): List<UserNameUiState> {
        return _userName
    }

    // Takes the user name input and adds it to the user name list
    fun addUserName(name: UserNameUiState) {
        _userName.add(name)
    }
}
```

User Signup Page:

```
@Composable
fun UserSignUpScreen(
navController: NavController
) {
    UserSignUpScreenInfo(
        username = "",
        navController
    )
}

@Composable
fun UserSignUpScreenInfo(
    username: String,
    navController: NavController,
    dropDownMenuViewModel: DropDownMenuViewModel = viewModel()
) {
    // Saves the state of the textfield
    val textFieldUserName = remember { mutableStateOf(username) }

    Column(
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "User Account",
            modifier = Modifier
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))
        Text(
            text = "User Account Name:",
        )
        Text(
            text = "This will be shown as the users' name only visible to the account",
            modifier = Modifier.padding(12.dp)
        )
        TextField(
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(color = Color.Transparent, shape = RoundedCornerShape(25))
                .padding(8.dp),
            placeholder = { Text(text =  "(i.e. Mandy)") },
            value = textFieldUserName.value,
            onValueChange = { textFieldUserName.value = it },
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Text)
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
        Row(){
            Button(
                onClick = {
                    if(textFieldUserName.value.isNotEmpty()) {
                        dropDownMenuViewModel.addUserName(
                            UserNameUiState(
                                userName = textFieldUserName.value,
                            )
                        )
                        textFieldUserName.value = ""
                    }
                }
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = "Add another user",
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .wrapContentWidth()
                )
            }
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(16.dp))
            Button(
                onClick = {
                    if(textFieldUserName.value.isNotEmpty()) {
                        dropDownMenuViewModel.addUserName(
                            UserNameUiState(
                                userName = textFieldUserName.value,
                            )
                        )
                    }
                    navController.navigate(DestinationScreens.HomePage.route)
                    Log.i("UserUIStateUpdate", dropDownMenuViewModel.getUserNameList().size.toString())
                }
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = "Next"
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Home Page:

```
@SuppressLint("UnusedMaterialScaffoldPaddingParameter")
@Composable
fun HomePage(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    navController: NavController
){
    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            HomePageTopAppBar()
        }
    ) {
        HelloWorld()
    }
}

@Composable
fun HomePageTopAppBar(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    dropDownMenuViewModel: DropDownMenuViewModel = viewModel()
) {

    // Setting up the menu button
    // State of menu
    var expandedMenu by remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }

    // Get list of names from ui state
    var listItems =
        dropDownMenuViewModel.getUserNameList()

    Row(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .background(color = Color.LightGray)
    ) {
        IconButton(
            onClick = {
                expandedMenu = true
            }
        ) {
            Icon(
                Icons.Filled.Menu,
                contentDescription = "Menu Button",
                tint = Color.DarkGray,
                modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
            )
        }
        DropdownMenu(
            expanded = expandedMenu,
            onDismissRequest = { expandedMenu = false },
        ) {
            listItems.forEach { user ->
                DropdownMenuItem(
                    onClick = { /*TODO*/ }
                ) {
                    Icon(
                        Icons.Filled.AccountCircle,
                        contentDescription = "Account",
                        tint = Color.DarkGray,
                    )
                    Text(
                        text = user.userName,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .padding(start = 4.dp),
                        color = Color.DarkGray
                    )
                }

            }
        }
        Text(
            text = "App",
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
            color = Color.Red,
        )
    }
    Divider(
        color = Color.DarkGray,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .width(1.dp)
    )
}

@Composable
fun HelloWorld(){
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize(),
    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
) {
    Text(
        text = "My App",
        color = Color.Red,
        style = MaterialTheme.typography.h1,
        textAlign = TextAlign.Center
    )
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so the problem is you are creating two instances of you viewmodel for each function that means that any info stored in the viewmodel passed to `UserSignUpScreenInfo` will not be in the viewmodel passed to `HomePageTopAppBar` because they are two diffrent things.

the fix is actualy easy what you have to do is for each passed instance of viewmodel you should not intialise it so you would have something like this:

```
@Composable
fun UserSignUpScreen(
navController: NavController,
viewmodel : DropDownMenuViewModel
) {
UserSignUpScreenInfo(
        username = "",
        navController,
        viewmodel
    )}

@Composable
fun UserSignUpScreenInfo(
    username: String,
    navController: NavController,
    ViewModel: DropDownMenuViewModel
) {
//somecode
}

@Composable
fun HomePage(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    navController: NavController,
    viewmodel: DropDownMenuViewModel
){
    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            HomePageTopAppBar(viewmodel)
        }
    ) {
        HelloWorld()
    }
}

@Composable
fun HomePageTopAppBar(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    dropDownMenuViewModel: DropDownMenuViewModel 
) {
//somecode
}
```

and now in outside your `NavHost` you are going to create an instance of `DropDownMenuViewModel` and pass it to both the screens:

```
   val viewModel = viewModel<DropDownMenuViewModel>()
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    NavHost(navController =navController, startDestination = "homepage" ){
          composable("homepage"){
                HomePageTopAppBar(
                    navController = navController, 
                    dropDownMenuViewModel = viewModel
                )
    
          }
          composable("home"){
             home(dropDownMenuViewModel = viewModel)
          }
   }
```

Comment: I marked the answer as the accepted answer but it will not let me press the up button, though it does say that my feedback has been recorded. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: @TurboScript yeah sorry you can't press the up arrow because your reputation is to low